# How can I pass arguments to pynput listener on_press function?

Tags: python, pynput

I made a minimal `pynput` program that does different actions when the `left` and `right` arrow keys are pressed. I want to turn this into a function that can take different values as arguments.

Here is a minimal working example without a function, and without arguments:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener 

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(key))

    if key == Key.esc:
        return False
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

**It prints the key you press, and quits when you press `esc`.**

And here is what I am trying to implement. Note that it doesn't work. Just look at the logic. **When `left` arrow is pressed, I want the program to execute a command that depends on a given argument. And vice versa for the right arrow.**

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key, left, right):
    if key == Key.left:
        print("{}'s key was pressed.".format(left))
    if key == Key.right:
        print("{}'s key was pressed.".format(right))

    if key == Key.esc:
        return False

def activate(name1, name2):
    with Listener(
            on_press=on_press(key, left=name1, right=name2)) as listener:
        listener.join()
        # when pressed, the program should print what on_press() is given as argument 

activate('Mark', 'John')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to leverage python closure to write callback functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54505851/how-to-leverage-python-closure-to-write-callback-functions)

Comment: not even close.

Comment: How is it not?  The way you “pass arguments” to a function that is *actually* being called by some other code is to make it a closure (or a bound method, especially if you have several different functions to which you wish to “pass” the same arguments).

Comment: I don't understand the question/answer, and it contains no explanation at all. i have nothing to work with

Comment: To be fair, that question is asking about a harder case—where you want the callback function to be *stateful*.  But the basic idea is just the same: define a function (with `def` or `lambda`) *inside* `activate` and pass it (without calling it, as always) to `Listener`.

Comment: Those concepts are very new to me. Why not just answer my question and get free reputation points?

Comment: First, my comments do constitute an answer (more than is perhaps desired).  Second, it’s silly to answer the same, basic questions repeatedly, and (notionally) it’s less effort to find a duplicate.  [Here’s one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/8586227) that you might like better, although I can’t change my close vote immediately to recommend it.

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but I had a similar case recently.
You can use:

```
def activate(name1, name2):
    with Listener(on_press=lambda event: on_press(event, left=name1, right=name2)) as listener:
        listener.join()
```